# How to use the response of a fetch 'POST'?

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api

I am getting stuck with this problem. I am using a fetch Post method to post in my server an object that i called "articulo".
Rigth now i have this code for the post:

```
async function postArticulo(articulo) {
    debugger
    const response = await fetch('http://192.168.100.3:3000/articulo', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(articulo)
    })
    const nuevoArticulo = await response.json();
    console.log(nuevoArticulo);
    return nuevoArticulo;
}
```

And in my server the route and the response is this(I use the express dependencie here):

```
async postArticulo(req, res){
        const articulo = req.body;
        if(articulo) console.log(articulo.nombre + ' Good');
        articulo.codigo = 87654321; //This is just for checking if i could change some value of the object
        console.log(articulo.codigo);
        return res.json({
            nombre: `${articulo.nombre}`,
            proveedor: `${articulo.proveedor}`,
            rubro: `${articulo.rubro}`,
            stock: `${articulo.stock}`,
            costo: `${articulo.costo}`,
            coeficiente: `${articulo.coeficiente}`,
            codigo: `${articulo.codigo}`
        });
    }
```

The problem i have: 
When i run this and post the object with the fetch Post method i get it good at the server, i can read and modify it. But when i send the response from the server with the same object i can not open it on the client. I tried the same i do with the client but through Imsomnia, and the server send the same object i post on it. On the client i get the same object, with the same properties, but the values are always "undefined" except for the numbers.
I have been four days now stuck on this problem and cant continue for this problem. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here i add the way i check the object before and after the fetch with console.log

Before:
`codigo: 12345678
coeficiente: "1.4"
costo: "425"
nombre: "Perro"
proveedor: "Whiskas"
rubro: "Alimento"
stock: "3"`

After:
`codigo: "87654321"
coeficiente: "undefined"
costo: "undefined"
nombre: "undefined"
proveedor: "undefined"
rubro: "undefined"
stock: "undefined"`

console.log(typeof req.body, req.body) server side:
object { codigoArticulo: 87654321 }

Comment: What does `console.log(articulo);` look like?

Comment: I will edit and add it

Comment: I meant what does it look like in the node console when it is the `req.body`

Comment: Please also post the result of `console.log(typeof req.body, req.body)` on the server. My bet is that it's not an object. How does the JSON get parsed on the server? If you're using standard libraries, you would need to send the appropriate content-type request header from the client with the data.

Comment: Yeah, u are rigth, that was. In any post i remember saying that was not needed at all so i never put it. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was not putting in headers the content-type, so the server never would know what was i really sending.